# Unable to load JS and CSS files for git pages from href link

Tags: html, git, github-pages

I have my git repo set up to use for git pages. 
Here is a link to my repo - [Github Repo](https://github.com/guptaraul89/guptaraul89.github.io) and here is my git page - [Git Page](https://guptaraul89.github.io/)

Not everything is being loaded on my git page whereas, on my local, all the page contents load perfectly. I am seeing a bunch of 404 errors in the console tab

Can someone point in the right direction of what I could be missing?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: you reference your `node_modules` directory in your GH pages -- those are the only assets that are getting 404's. Have you tried moving those assets into the relevant `/js` and `/css` folders to see if it renders correctly? I would take a look at the [GH Jekyll docs on assets](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) for how you might do this

Comment: @phd node_modules, I have animation on my page that doesnt work on git pages